# REST Update Child Object - Prevent Id field From Changing

Tags: rest, put

Suppose I have the following object graph that a client could submit in an HTTP PUT request to update my parent object

```
{
  "Id": 123,
  "FirstName": "Joe",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Schools": [
    {
      "Id": 444,
      "Name": "Fun University"
    },
    {
      "Id": 555,
      "Name": "Unfun University"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my service, the only way to update a school is via the Student.  However, I can't necessarily prevent the client from modifying the "444" id.

My question is:
1. Is it safe enough to just validate on the server that the school with id 444 belongs to student with id 123?
2. Or, does my client need to make a request for the student using the student service, and then using the list of schools on the student service, call a school service (which I'd create) and do the PUT there?

In scenario 1, I'd update the entire object using http://www.mydomain.com/api/students/123 (PUT).

In scenario 2, I'd update just the school object using http://www.mydomain.com/api/schools/444 (PUT)

As of now, my intent was approach #1, but is this not a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it safe enough ...

to just validate on the server that the school with id 444 belongs to student with id 123

**Why at all check for dependencies?**
If you just edit a school this should have no whatsover interest for the student resource.

just issue your `PUT /student/123/school/444` and handle it. If it makes sense for your customers to have a more direct access just implement `/school/{ID}` as a new service.

I think what you really need is a `ID-not-changeable constraint`.
Just prohibit any user from changing the ID of a resource via a put request. Changing IDs is only needed seldomly and should be handled extra carefully because of the implications (relationships for all students must be updated then).

A `PUT /students/123` should not be allowed to alter the schools itself but merely the students relationship to them (remove them from the student or add new additionals).
The code with which you handle this is all up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Is there a some kind of standard for id-not-changeable?  In either case, I think choice 2 is better.

Comment: I think so too. When handling those put-requests I fetch the resource by ID provided in the URL and remove the ID sent in the Request-Body from the request. This just ignores the ID value sent in the body. you could do a match with the URL-ID and throw errors back at the user and/or log it. REST says the PUT should work on the entity referenced by the URI. Add a line to your docs that customers can't change IDs and you're fine.